# strange minor modes and how to diminish them

Tags: python, mode-line

I am working in a python file and thought I have diminished all modes accordingly, also yapfify. However, that does not seem to be the case as one can see in the screenshot. What are those cryptic modes anyway?

Also, yapfify spamms my entire buffer list full.

Can anyone tell me why and how I fix that

[image]

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you want help here regarding some specific package that you discover is causing the problem, the please provide the requisite background information. E.g. if "yapify" is a culprit, point to that package, describe how you use it (recipe), etc.

Comment: Assuming you're running a gui Emacs, what happens when you click on the minor mode, then in the pop-up-menu click "Help for Minor Mode"?

Comment: Have you looked at [yapfify's github](https://github.com/JorisE/yapfify) for any [issues relating to buffers](https://github.com/JorisE/yapfify/issues/14)?

Comment: Assuming they *are* minor modes, then you can refer to `C-h v minor-mode-alist`.